# ¿Cómo firmar XML con XAdES-EPES?

Tags: c#, xml

Necesito firmar un XML con las siguientes especificaciones:

1. Se ajusta la versión del ETSI TS 101 903 a v1.3.2 o superior.
2. Se agrega el URL a utilizar para la pólitica del XAdES-EPES.
3. Se aclara que el empaquetado del XAdES será ENVELOPED.
4. Se indica que los algoritmos de encriptación de los certificados deben ser RSA 2048 o RSA 4096.
5. Se indica que los algoritmos de digest de la firma deben ser SHA-256 y SHA-512.
6. Se agrega texto acerca de la Ley 8454.
7. Se agrega ejemplo de una etiqueta ds:Signature.
8. Se modifica el valor del ID de la política a versión v4.1
9. Se cambia el ejemplo de firma para que tenga la información del Policy en la versión v4.1

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Intenté firmarlo con la forma habitual de la siguiente manera, pero de esa forma no cumple con los requisitos solicitados:

```
// Create a new CspParameters object to specify a key container.
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = "010945029010.p12";

                //XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY

                // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

                // Create a new XML document.
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                xmlDoc.Load(strRuta);

                // Sign the XML document. 
                SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

                // Save the document.
                xmlDoc.Save(strRuta);

// Check arguments.
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
        if (Key == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Key");

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
```

Comment: Hola, pudiste firmar el XML?

Comment: Si, descargue el siguiente sistema que lo realiza: https://github.com/ctt-gob-es/FirmaXadesNet45

Comment: Hola, tendrás un ejemplo de cómo firmar el xml con Xades-EPES. Lo podrías poner como respuesta por favor?

Comment: Buenas, lograste que te validaran la firma? Es que yo estoy haciendo la factura electrónica para Costa Rica, pero me dicen que la firma es invalida.

Comment: @ArnoldUlateSegura me gustaria contactarme con usted para detallar unas dudas sobre la libreria, es posible ?

Answer (score 0):

He adelantado algo tal vez te sirva aunque no es valida:

```
 public string FirmarXadesEpes(string path)
        {
            error = "true";
            try
            {
                /* X509Certificate2Collection selectedCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
                 selectedCertificates = ElejirCertificado();             
                 X509Certificate2 certificado = selectedCertificates[0];  */

                X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2();
                certificado = ElegirCertificado();
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                /* CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                 cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";
                 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams); */
                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

                xmlDoc.Load(path);
                error =FirmaXadesEPES(xmlDoc, certificado,path);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { error = ex.ToString(); }
            return error;
        }


        private string  FirmaXadesEPES(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate,string path)
        {
            idFirma = IdSignature();
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);


            string URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
            string uri = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
            try
            {
                signedXml.Signature.Id = "Id-" + idFirma;
                signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
                signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

                signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
                KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
                keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
                signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
                //Reference 1
                Reference reference = new Reference();
                reference.Id = "r-id-" + idFirma;
                reference.Type = "";
                reference.Uri = "";
                XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform("not(ancestor-or-self::Signature)", xmlDoc);
                reference.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
                reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
                reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
                signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                //Reference 2
                Reference reference2 = new Reference();
                reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
                reference2.Uri = "";
                reference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
                reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
                signedXml.AddReference(reference2);
                signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                // /////////////////////////////////
                XmlElement qualifyingPropertiesRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "QualifyingProperties", URI);
                qualifyingPropertiesRoot.SetAttribute("Target", "#SignatureId", URI);

                XmlElement SignedSignatureProperties = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignedSignatureProperties", URI);

                XmlElement signaturePropertiesRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignedProperties", URI);
                signaturePropertiesRoot.SetAttribute("Id", "SignedPropertiesId", URI);

                XmlElement timestamp = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SigningTime", URI);
                timestamp.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"); //2011-09-05T09:11:24.268Z
                SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(timestamp);

                XmlElement SigningCertificate = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SigningCertificate", URI);
                XmlElement Cert = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "Cert", URI);
                XmlElement CertDigest = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "CertDigest", URI);

                SHA1 cryptoServiceProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] sha1 = cryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(certificate.RawData);

                XmlElement DigestMethod = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "DigestMethod", URI);

                DigestMethod.SetAttribute("Algorithm", SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url);
                XmlElement DigestValue = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "DigestValue", URI);
                DigestValue.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1);
                CertDigest.AppendChild(DigestMethod);
                CertDigest.AppendChild(DigestValue);
                Cert.AppendChild(CertDigest);

                XmlElement IssuerSerial = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "IssuerSerial", URI);
                XmlElement X509IssuerName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "X509IssuerName", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
                X509IssuerName.InnerText = certificate.IssuerName.Name;
                XmlElement X509SerialNumber = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "X509SerialNumber", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
                X509SerialNumber.InnerText = certificate.SerialNumber;
                IssuerSerial.AppendChild(X509IssuerName);
                IssuerSerial.AppendChild(X509SerialNumber);
                Cert.AppendChild(IssuerSerial);

                SigningCertificate.AppendChild(Cert);
                SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(SigningCertificate);

                signaturePropertiesRoot.AppendChild(SignedSignatureProperties);
                qualifyingPropertiesRoot.AppendChild(signaturePropertiesRoot);

                XmlElement SignaturePolicyIdentifier = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignaturePolicyIdentifier", URI);
                SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(SignaturePolicyIdentifier);

                XmlElement SignaturePolicyId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignaturePolicyId", URI);
                SignaturePolicyIdentifier.AppendChild(SignaturePolicyId);

                XmlElement SigPolicyId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SigPolicyId", URI);
                SignaturePolicyId.AppendChild(SigPolicyId);

                XmlElement Identifier = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "Identifier", URI);
                Identifier.InnerText = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.2/ResolucionComprobantesElectronicosDGT-R-48-2016_4.2.pdf";
                SigPolicyId.AppendChild(Identifier);

                XmlElement SigPolicyHash = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SigPolicyHash", URI);
                SignaturePolicyId.AppendChild(SigPolicyHash);

                DigestMethod = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "DigestMethod", URI);
                DigestMethod.SetAttribute("Algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
                DigestValue = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "DigestValue", URI);
                /* byte[] shaCertificate = { 0x06, 0xb3, 0x90, 0xb6, 0x45, 0xbb, 0x68, 0x3a, 0xde, 0x72, 0x8e, 0xb8, 0xf9, 0x79, 0x27, 0xd9, 0x18, 0x01, 0x67, 0xdb };
                 SHA256 sigPolicyHash = SHA256Managed.Create();
                 byte[] sigPolicyHashValue = sigPolicyHash.ComputeHash(shaCertificate);
                 DigestValue.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(sigPolicyHashValue);*/
                DigestValue.InnerText = "eUGBLxo7SaqxaR+CGU5DCjUc514GOiOU9S0Smy5W7HE=";
                //"V8lVVNGDCPen6VELRD1Ja8HARFk="; "NmI5Njk1ZThkNzI0MmIzMGJmZDAyNDc4YjUwNzkzODM2NTBiOWUxNTBkMmI2YjgzYzZjM2I5NTZlNDQ4OWQzMQ=="; "LpeabLa3KYF9gfEAYYMFtkhtoR8=";"5EsGNDZGSknyxAIJSI+u0dERTL0=";
                SigPolicyHash.AppendChild(DigestMethod);
                SigPolicyHash.AppendChild(DigestValue);

                XmlElement SignedDataObjectProperties = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignedDataObjectProperties", URI);

                XmlElement DataObjectFormat = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "DataObjectFormat", URI);
                DataObjectFormat.SetAttribute("ObjectReference", "#r-id-1");
                signaturePropertiesRoot.AppendChild(SignedDataObjectProperties);
                SignedDataObjectProperties.AppendChild(DataObjectFormat);
                XmlElement MimeType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "MimeType", URI);
                MimeType.InnerText = "application/octet-stream";
                DataObjectFormat.AppendChild(MimeType);


                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject
                {
                    Data = qualifyingPropertiesRoot.SelectNodes("."),
                };
                signedXml.AddObject(dataObject);
                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

                XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
                bool checkSign = signedXml.CheckSignature();

            } catch (Exception ex) { error = ex.ToString(); }

            xmlDoc.Save(path);
            //return xmlDoc.OuterXml;
            return error;
        }


        private static XmlDsigXPathTransform CreateXPathTransform(string XPathString, XmlDocument doc)
        {
            XmlElement xPathElem = doc.CreateElement("XPath");
            xPathElem.InnerText = XPathString;
            XmlDsigXPathTransform xForm = new XmlDsigXPathTransform();
            xForm.LoadInnerXml(xPathElem.SelectNodes("."));
            return xForm;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

En España tenemos un cliente muy potente al cual le podemos especificar por parámetros como queremos firmar así como las políticas o tipos de firmas ajustándose perfectamente a los requisitos que necesitas, es muy robusto.
Es una aplicación que se instala del lado del cliente y realiza las firmas electronicas de la manera en la que se la has especificado.

Aplicación de firmas: [Autofirma](http://firmaelectronica.gob.es/Home/Descargas.html)

Puedes validarlas en : [eValide](https://valide.redsara.es/valide/?)

La manera de invocar al aplicativo es a través de código javaScript : [Aquí](https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ctt/clienteafirma/descargas#.Wz3CJdIzbcs) podéis encontrar información sobre como invocar Autofirma así como el código JavaScritp necesario para su funcionamiento.

Cualquier pregunta podeis ponerme un comentario.

Saludos.